# Using my putty ssh tunnel with my iPhone or PS3

Tags: ssh, proxy, iphone, putty, tunnel

I'm living in a student residence, which has a proxy blocking a high number of things. I have a (virtual) private server, running with ubuntu 12.04 LTS, with an openssh server.

I have configured a tunnel on my laptop (Windows 7 64bits) with putty: Connection>>SSH>>Tunnels and I added a new forwarded port: Dynamic on port 8080. I use this port with my programs (Firefox etc.) in Socks5 mode and it does bypass my residence proxy well! (Actually I even use proxifier in order to set my tunnel or the original proxy at will).

My problem is that I would want to be able to use this tunnel with my iPhone (and later my PS3). I'm able to put those on the same wireless network using the adhoc wifi networks with windows 7. What I tried to do is to set the proxy of my iphone to be the ip address of my laptop on the network and the port to be 8080. But it does not work. I'm sure the ip address of the laptop is correct because I can access my laptop http server.

Is my approach ok ? Or could it be a firewall problem ?

Thank you for reading my issue!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any special settings on your iPhone and PS3. Since you created an ad hoc WiFi network, you can configure it to share the internet connection. On iPhone connect to the ad hoc network directly, no proxies. Then manually assign it an IP (eg 192.168.1.2), set the subnet mask (usually 255.255.255.0) and the gateway to the IP of the wireless adaptor of the host computer (eg 192.168.1.1). The DNS server can be the same with the gateway (eg 192.168.1.1), but if this doesn't work you must set it to the actual DNS server of the ISP (for example, for OTENET in Greece this is 195.170.1.1 and 195.170.2.2). I'm not familiar with Ubuntu, but sure there is a command to reveal the network settings, so you can find out which DNS are assigned by the server each time you connect. They should more or less have the same IP, they usually don't change. At the host, you have to manually configure the wireless adapter to an IP (eg 192.168.1.1) set the subnet mask to 255.255.255.0 and the gateway to the IP of the wired connection. DNS servers must be those of ISP.

If you do that, it will hopefully share the internet connection though the ad hoc network, so you have access to the internet for your iPhone too. Since there is no restriction at the wireless ad hoc network, you don't need to setup and proxies. Only the host must use the proxy to make the tunneling work. The iPhone can connect directly to the host which will connect to the internet via the proxy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I don't understand everything: am I not obliged to specify somewhere that I want to use my tunnel on the port 8080 (by putty) ?
It seems to me that you're telling me to do something like that:

iPhone--(wirelessConnection)-->Windows--(gateway)--(wireConnection)-->SchoolProxy-->Internet

I'm trying to achieve something like that:

iPhone--(wirelessConnection)-->Putty--(gateway)--(wireConnection)-->[SchoolProxy]-->Internet

I have to admit I'm still a bit confused.

I don't manage to find how to set up the subnet mask and gateway for my wireless network in windows 7.